# Functional calculus: Does $A$ commute with $e^{iA^2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $A$ be an unbounded self-adjoint operator. Is it then true that $A$ commutes with $e^{iA^2}$? This sounds natural to me but I have no clue whether this is true in general. The problem is that we only did such a functional calculus for bounded(!) operators, so I don't even know whether something similarly exists for unbounded ones?

Comment: You might want to read about semigroups of operators from some functional analysis book. In general it depends on your $A$ to define $e^{iA^2}$. In many cases it will not be true, because the domain of $A$ does not have to be the entire space.

Comment: @QiyuWen I know this and if you read the question again, you see that $A$ is an unbounded self-adjoint operator. So if $A$ was defined on the entire space then $A$ would not be unbounded.

Comment: It should be mentioned that unbounded symmetric operators are not necessarily self-adjoint.

Comment: @KeithMcClary why? nobody questioned that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spectral Theorem for $A$ is given in terms of a Borel Spectral measure $E$
$$
                  Ax = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lambda dE(\lambda)x,
$$
and $x \in \mathcal{D}(A)$ iff
$$
            \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lambda^2 d\|E(\lambda)x\|^2 < \infty.
$$
The operator $e^{iA^2}$ is defined through the functional calculus as
$$
     e^{iA^2}x = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\lambda^2}dE(\lambda)x.
$$
This operator is unitary. For bounded Borel functions $f$, $g$, the operators $f(A)$ and $g(A)$ are bounded operators that satisfy
$$
       \int f(\lambda)dE(\lambda) \int g(\lambda) dE(\lambda)x = \int (fg)(\lambda)dE(\lambda)x,\;\;\; x\in\mathcal{H}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
            \int_{-R}^{R}\lambda dE(\lambda) e^{iA^2}x = \int_{-R}^{R}\lambda e^{iA^2}dE(\lambda)x  =e^{iA^2}\int_{-R}^{R}\lambda dE(\lambda)x \\
             \int_{-R}^{R}\lambda^2 d\|E(\lambda)e^{iA^2}x\|^2 =
\int_{-R}^{R}\lambda^2 d\|E(\lambda)x\|^2.
$$
As $R\rightarrow\infty$, the conclusion from the last integral is that $x\in\mathcal{D}(A)$ iff $e^{iA^2}x\in\mathcal{D}(A)$. Furthermore, using the first vector identity,
$$
          Ae^{iA^2}x = e^{iA^2}Ax,\;\;\; x\in\mathcal{D}(A).
$$

Comment: In fact, you can replace $e^{iA^2}$ by $f(A)$, where $f: \mathbb R_{\geq 0} \to \mathbb C$ is any bounded Borel function, since this fact seems to be the only property of $e^{iA^2}$ that you've used in the proof.

Comment: @BerniWaterman : I used the fact that $e^{iA^2}$ is unitary.

Comment: Right, in the norm equality in the second-to-last equation. Wouldn't a general bounded $f$ give you a norm inequality instead and would that not also be sufficient ?

Comment: @BerniWaterman : Boundedness would not lead to equality of the two domains. Boundedness above and below would.

Comment: I actually had something a little different in mind. In my example, $f$ is a rapidly-decreasing Borel function. In this case, I am very certain that both $f(A) \cdot A$ and $A \cdot f(A)$ extend to the same bounded, everywhere defined operator.

Comment: @BerniWaterman : If that's the class of functions you're interested in, then that would work because $\lambda f(\lambda)$ would be uniformly bounded.